# Can I reuse a Fragment from one Component in another Component in React?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have a Fragment in a React Component that I want to use in a separate component, is there any way I could reuse the Fragment?

Here is the Fragment from the first component that I want to access:

```
  <Fragment>
{this.state.sharing === false ? (
  <div className="video-container">
    {this.renderNoInternet()}
    {this.renderRedirect()}
    <AudoUpdatePopup />
    <Header
      me={this.state.me}
      logoutHandler={this.logoutHandler}
      changeCameraStatus={this.changeCameraStatus}
      changeMicrophoneStatus={this.changeMicrophoneStatus}
      audioDevices={this.state.audioDevices}
      videoDevices={this.state.videoDevices}
      onChangeCamera={this.changeCamerahandler}
      onChangeMicrophone={this.changeMicrophoneHandler}
      knocking={{
        beingKnocked: this.state.beingKnocked.status,
        knocking: this.state.knocking.status,
        callAccepted: this.state.callAccepted,
      }}
    />

    <div className="user-container">
      {this.state.me.cameraStatus === "Out"
        ? null
        : this.state.coworkers.map((user, index) => {
            if (user.id !== parseInt(localStorage.getItem("me.id")))
              return (
                <UserThumbnail
                  onClick={this.startCall}
                  key={index}
                  user={user}
                  knocking={{
                    beingKnocked: this.state.beingKnocked.status,
                    knocking: this.state.knocking.status,
                    callAccepted: this.state.callAccepted,
                  }}
                />
              );
            else return null;
          })}
      <div
        className={
          this.state.beingKnocked.status === true ||
          this.state.callAccepted === true ||
          this.state.knocking.status === true
            ? "user-video opacity-cont-hide"
            : "user-video"
        }
        style={{ marginLeft: "8px" }}
      >
        <Link
          to="/InviteCoworker"
          onClick={() => {
            try {
              WebRTC.leaveWorkspace(this.workspaceId);
              WebRTC.disconnect();
            } catch (e) {}
          }}
        >
          <button className="invite-button">
            <img
              alt="User"
              src={require("../../assets/images/add-button.jpg")}
            />
            <p className="invite-text">Invite</p>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      {this.myIndex !== -1 ? (
        <UserThumbnail
          onClick={this.startCall}
          user={this.state.coworkers[this.myIndex]}
          knocking={{
            beingKnocked: this.state.beingKnocked.status,
            knocking: this.state.knocking.status,
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
      {this.state.me.cameraStatus === "Out" &&
      this.state.activeUsers >= 0 ? (
        <p className="set-status-text">
          {this.activeUsersText}
          <br />
          <br />
          <p
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createNoPermissionMarkup()}
          ></p>
        </p>
      ) : null}
      {this.state.coworkers.length === 0 &&
      this.state.me.cameraStatus !== "Out" ? (
        <p className="set-status-text">
          <br />
          Feels a little quiet in here.
          <br />
          Invite some friends or coworkers.
        </p>
      ) : null}

      {this.state.beingKnocked.status === true ? (
        <BeingKnocked
          payload={this.state.beingKnocked}
          streams={this.streams}
          hangUpCall={this.hangupCall.bind(this)}
          acceptCall={this.acceptCall.bind(this)}
        />
      ) : null}
      {this.state.knocking.status === true ? (
        <Knocking
          payload={this.state.knocking}
          streams={this.streams}
          hangUpCall={this.hangupCall.bind(this)}
        />
      ) : null}
      {this.state.callAccepted === true ? (
        <CallScreen
          { ...this.props } me={this.state.me} coworkers={this.state.coworkers}
          knocking={{
            beingKnocked: this.state.beingKnocked.status,
            knocking: this.state.knocking.status,
            callAccepted: this.state.callAccepted,
          }}
          // next try props=this.props state=this.state, then try props=...this.props state=...this.state
          // hangUpCall={this.hangupCall.bind(this)}
          // secondPartyStream={this.state.secondPartyStream}
          // startScreenShare={this.startScreenShare.bind(this)}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  </div>
) : (
  <ShareScreen
    sharerVideo={this.state.sharerStream}
    myVideo={this.state.me.myClearVideo}
    micLevel={this.state.me.micAudioLevel}
    stopScreenShare={this.state.sharer ? this.hangupCall : this.stopScreenShare}
    //stopScreenShare={this.hangupCall} // This line of code will hangup the call when the screen share is over (MARK)
    sharer={this.state.sharer}
    secondPartyStream={this.state.secondPartyStream}
  />
)}
```

And I want to access it in another component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import UserThumbnail from "./UserThumbnail";
import AudoUpdatePopup from "./AudoUpdatePopup";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import WebRTC from "../../assets/js/webrtc.js";
import BeingKnocked from "./screens/BeingKnocked";
import Knocking from "./screens/Knocking";
import CallScreen from "./screens/CallScreen";
import Header from "./Header";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

// Styling
const h1Style = {
    width: '107px',
    height: '27px',
    fontFamily: 'Lato',
    fontSize: '22px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStretch: 'normal',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 'normal',
    letterSpacing: '-0.73px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: "#000062",
};
const modalStyle = {
    display: 'none',
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: 1,
};
const modalContentStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
};

export class AddressingPopup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            // Fragment goes here
        );
    }
}
export default AddressingPopup;
```

I just need the same functionality from the first fragment in the second.

Comment: Can you please show your code please?

Comment: @Arnab done, just added it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly,  you want to use the design and functionality from the previous component to the second one. In that case , you can simply export the first component and import it in the second one. You can then add that component in the return function.  Other than that, its not possible to use a code from one file to another